# How to force full garbage collection in .NET 4.x?

Tags: c#, .net, weak-references

I've a problem with WeakReferences in .NET 4.x, 
I was running tests to make sure some objects were not referenced anymore (using WeakReferences) and I noticed the behavior is not consistent across framework versions:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class WeakReferenceTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestWeakReferenceIsDisposed()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference(new StringBuilder("Hello"));

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        GC.Collect();

        var retrievedSb = weakRef.Target as StringBuilder;
        Assert.That(retrievedSb, Is.Null);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
.NET 2.0  PASS
.NET 3.0  FAIL
.NET 3.5  PASS
.NET 4.0  FAIL
.NET 4.5  FAIL
```

Is this documented somewhere?

Is there a way to force the GC to collect that reference in .NET 4.5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note: GC does not collect unreachable objects in debug mode.

Comment: Hmm, the code you've shown works for me on all versions of the framework. (Well, I don't have NUnit installed, so I'm just using `Debug.Assert` but that should not change the behavior.)

Comment: Not sure if .NET platform is the best solution if you need to precisely control disposing of objects... Every learning resource says quite clearly - you can't predict when GC happens nor should you try to force it...

Comment: Just to build on what @walther mentioned, even if you do invoke the garbage collector, there is no guarantee that it will execute.

Comment: @Cody Gray: perhaps NUnit or NCrunch is doing something weird, I'll look into that. (walther: yes I know but it's the easiest way I found to check behavior of an external assembly.)

Comment: @Cody Gray You're right it's NUnit or my test runner that's messing with this. (Even compiled in DEBUG this test pass on all versions)

Comment: @Cody Gray post your comment as an answer since it's the solution, I'll accept it

Comment: I use NCrunch and it was instrumenting the output assembly, producing this behavior (disabling output instrumenting make the test pass on all platforms)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is related to NCrunch. The code works fine on my machine for all versions of the framework if I replace the test with a simple call to `Debug.Assert`:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class WeakReferenceTests
{
    public void TestWeakReferenceIsDisposed()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference(new StringBuilder("Hello"));

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        GC.Collect();

        var retrievedSb = weakRef.Target as StringBuilder;
        Debug.Assert(retrievedSb == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was NCrunch that instruments assemblies, I disabled the option and it pass.

Comment: I'm trying to get this done, but my application is built on Silverlight 4, and I don't have the WaitForFullGCComplete option. Would it be on SL5?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ Cody Gray (see comments), I figured that out.

I use NCrunch to run my tests and it was instrumenting the output assembly, producing this behavior (disabling output instrumenting make the test pass on all platforms).