# WaitForFullGCComplete vs (WaitForPendingFinalizers + collect)?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-4.5

I'm having a trouble to understand what is the difference between `WaitForFullGCComplete`  and  `WaitForPendingFinalizers + collect`.

I already know that when a new object is created (*which has a finalizer* ) —  A reference to that object is created  in the `finalization queue`.
Now -  when a `GC .collect` occurs and finds that the object should be collected , the reference from the `finalization queue` *moves* to the `f-reachable queue`.

These references in the queue are considered as a `root` . Now — a special thread  awakes from sleep at the `f-reachable queue` and run each object's `finalize` method .

Notice this is done AFTER the `collect` phase. So only the next time we run `GC.collect` the object would be truly gone.

If we want to wait until the `f-reachable queue's` thread is done with all the `finalize` methods - we should call : `WaitForPendingFinalizers`.

And now if we want full collect , then we should run GC.collect again!.

If so - it seems that a *full* GC can be made by :

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
```

So why would I need  `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()` ?

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforfullgccomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) says :

> Returns the status of a registered notification for determining
>   whether a full, blocking garbage collection by the common language
>   runtime has completed.

**Question**

I don't understand  : I **already** know when Gc has completed and it is at that point :

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
//HERE <--
```

So when should I use that method as opposed to my code?

NB

(I saw it's usages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28259405/859154) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771853/859154)  )

but their usage is not complete because  - Not to mention that there is *another* method which should must  be called in pairs :

From CLR via C# 4:

> Note that you should always call the `WaitForFullGCApproach` and
>   `WaitForFullGCComplete` methods in pairs  because the CLR handles them
>   as pairs internally.

Comment: In your `Collect` based code, yes, you know at the `HERE` point that a collection has finished - but in order to do that, you had to *force* a collection to occur (which is generally the wrong thing to do in any code outside of benchmarks). The `WaitForXXX` methods are for you to react to a collection happening - whether that collection occurred because you forced it to or, more naturally, because the system decided a GC should occur.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. That makes things clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood, both the usages in the link you've pointed out is wrong. As you quoted from CLR via C#, both `WaitForFullGCApproach` and `WaitForFullGCComplete` should be used in pairs.

`WaitForFullGCComplete` is very different than `Collect + WaitForPendingFinalizers`. Its usage is completely different.

Lets say you're writing a high performance, low latency server application which handles several thousands of requests per second. Obviously the server will allocate considerable amount of memory which can trigger a full gc(blocking!) which is a bad news for us.

Yes full gc will take a while to complete, till then you can't process the requests from clients (as your threads will be suspended). It isn't desirable for a high performance application to tolerate a full gc at peak hours.

In such case, if you want to redirect the further requests to some other server which can handle them, you'd use `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification`, `GC.WaitForFullGCApproach` and `GC.WaitForFullGCComplete` methods respectively.

`WaitForFullGCApproach` will block till the GC decides to do a full gc, it is a notification for you to proactively redirect the requests or take some action.

Then `WaitForFullGCComplete` will block till the full gc is completed. It is a notification for you to start processing the requests again.

[GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a good example and explains it better.

Comment: But if the server is doing doing a GC now and it takes time , then there is NO CODE that can run to redirect . I'm referencing to your  : _"if you want to redirect the further requests to some other server "_. If it was in the IIS level - I would understand. but it's not. I mean it's like a thread which is blocked but still runs a code which redirects ???? Do you see my problem here?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know about web requests(I can't comment on that) Let's say it is a windows service or console application listening for requests. When `WaitForFullGCApproach` returns, GC is not yet started --which means your threads can run. Let's say there is another program which actually finds the right server to get the job done, you can notify that server about the GC and it will find another server which is responsive to send the request. Got the idea?